# Implicit animation not working

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

As I'm trying to override implicit animation on the `position` property, the layer quickly flashes to the destination position and then starts my explicit animation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
animation.path = path; // some CGPath
animation.duration = 1.0;

[newTopLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(x, y)]; // Setting final values for stickness
[newTopLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

It seem that the `position` key doesn't get overriden. Why?
I tried it with `CATransaction`, but still no luck.

**Update**
Further investigations had shown, that the `newTopLayer` is not implicitly animated anyway. For info: it's backed by an `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's that simple: if a `CALayer` is backed by `UIView`, then all implicit animations are disabled. If you need an implicit animation, make a sub-layer to a `UIView`'s layer.